# Why radio buttons are not being checked after clicking in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a To-Do app using react, where I have radio buttons to check the priority of a Todo. However, any of my radio buttons are not being checked when I click it. I am using chrome, windows 10.

**One of my radio buttons Codes:**

```
    <input className="form-check-input"                        
    type="radio"                           
    name="priorityOptions"                         
    id="priorityLow"                            
    value="Low"                            
    checked={this.state.todo_priority === 'Low'}                              
    onChange={this.onChageTodoPriority}                                  
     />                                      
    <label className="form-check-lebel">Low</label>
```

**On submit codes:**

```
    onSubmit(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('form_submitted');
                console.log('Todo description:' + 
    this.state.todo_description);
        console.log('Todo Responsible:' + 
    this.state.todo_responsible);
        console.log('Todo Priority:' + 
    this.state.todo_priority);
        console.log('Todo Completed:' +  
    this.state.todo_completed);
        this.setState({
            todo_description:'',
            todo_responsible:'',
            todo_priority: '',
            todo_completed: false
        })
    }
```

**onChangeTodoPriority Listener:**

```
    onChangeTodoPriority(e){
        this.setState({
            todo_priority: e.target.value
        });
    }
```

I am logging all the form informations in the console. Text inputs are showing. but radio inputs are not showing in the console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your `onChageTodoPriority` listener.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the onChageTodoPriority listener code.

Comment: Have you tried to add `console.log(e.target.value)` inside the `onChageTodoPriority` listener to see that you get the correct value? Checkboxes are typically used based on their `checked` property, not value (you can't uncheck the checkbox if you only check its value.)

Comment: I can not click any of the radio buttons. It seems like unclickable.

Comment: You mean that nothing happens when you click them. Then `onChageTodoPriority` isn't bound correctly, or some other element is obscuring the checkboxes. Not enough information in the question to tell.

Comment: Yes, exactly. nothing is happening when I click them.

Comment: `this.onChageTodoPriority` doesn't match the name of your function. You also explicitly set the `value` and never change it; the target value will always be the same.

Comment: Yes exactly that happened, I made a spelling mistake: onChang instead of onChange. Thanks, guys, problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.onChageTodoPriority` doesn't match the name of your function.

You also explicitly set `value` and never change it; the target value will always be the same.